# Web.py not serving static files

Tags: python, web.py

Running on the devel server, I can render 0.0.0.0:8080/index.html without CSS fine, but no static files load.  0.0.0.0:8080/static results in "Not found" and 0.0.0.0:8080/static/style.css gets a 404.

All I've googled quotes or links to http://webpy.org/cookbook/staticfiles, which I feel like I've followed to point.

filetree

```
code.py
/web
    ...
/static
    style.css
    /images
        ...
/pages
    index.html
```

code.py

```
import web

render = web.template.render('/home/keith/code/webpy/skeleton/pages/')

urls = (
    '/', 'index',)

class index:
    def GET(self):
        return render.index()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

/pages/index.html

```
...
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/style.css" />
...
```

Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried running `python code.py` from a terminal window and the static files served fine!  Before, I was using the terminal emulator in my IDE (Geany 1.24.1).  So that was the problem, for whatever reason.